# No Vs. None - in this case both Ok?

Tags: negation, determiners

Please look at the statement which I correct. I searched for duplicates about "none" and found that in fact those might be both correct.

Please let me know if my assumptions are right.

- She has none cigarettes.

And

- She has no cigarettes.

Comment: **She has no cigarettes** is correct, the other is not.

Comment: Does she have any cigarettes? She has none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case "she has no cigarettes" would be correct, but "she has none cigarettes" would not. The word "none" cannot be used in that manner. It is usually used as a pronoun, which can't modify nouns such as "cigarettes." "No" works well in the same place. It can be used to modify nouns.

As pointed out in comments, "she has none" could work as an answer to "does she have any cigarettes?" This is a result of none being used properly as a pronoun and the object of the sentence.